# Raster multivariate regression

Tags: raster, statistics, regression

I am looking for advice on how to set up a multivariate regression using raster data. My dependent variable is the location of firms in a specific industry.
My independent variables are:

- lease rates
- Within 1 mile of large firm
- within 1 mile of incubator
- within 1 mile of university
- within 0.5 miles of freeway
- In industrial zoned area

Using the band collection statistics tool, I can get correlations, but this does not give me the multivariate regression model I am looking for. I could export and run in another statistical software, but I can't figure out how to make the grid identical, and also the attribute table for rasters does not give coordinates or specify each cell so that I can match records across variables.

Any advice on this? I am open to any solution!

Comment: If any then convert any raster to points and sample the rest of them

Comment: The problem you've described doesn't seem well suited for multivariate regression because it's mostly categorical and not continuous data. Even if your independent variables were continuous, your dependent variable would need to be some sort of continuous attribute associated with the location information. Have you considered generating a kernel density map and masking out areas that don't meet your criteria? You could also tabulate scores for your categorical variables (+1 point for each criteria met in a location) and summarize density values based on the scores.